# Initialize Const variable of struct

Tags: c++, data-structures, struct

Looked around at several other questions and answers, but I can't seem to figure out how to apply it to my situation.

Here is my setup:

```
typdef struct sensor {
    const unsigned char pin;

    //otherVariables
}Sensor;

Sensor *left = new Sensor();

void initStruct() {
    left->pin = 1; //illegal initialization
}
```

From what I have been reading my below code seems like a possible solution, but I'm not near my compiler so I cannot test. Does that look right? can you offer a solution if it is wrong?

```
void initStruct() {
    left->pin = malloc(sizeOf char);
    left->pin = 1;
}
```

Comment: How about you provide the output from the compiler?

Comment: @Melon: Read the question properly.. !!!

Comment: `left->pin = malloc(sizeOf char);` what? You can only allocate memory to pointers, not to a `const unsigned char`.

Comment: Do you have a good reason for dynamic allocation? `Sensor left = {1 /*, other variables */};` is the obvious solution, if it's an aggregate. Otherwise, give it a constructor.

Comment: @MikeSeymour because I am declaring the sensors globally to be accessed by multiple functions. I am open to suggestions of better methods

Comment: @Adjit: You don't need `new` to create global variables.

Comment: Ah ok. It's been a while since I've used C/C++ extensively so just trying to dust off the cobwebs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No that code does not make sense.

1. The `pin` member is `const` so you can't assign to it except in the initializer.
2. The `pin` member, is not a pointer so assgning `malloc()` to it is not going to compile correctly.

I think you need to remove `const` from the `struct` field, that doesn't make any sense at all. If you want to prevent accidentally modifying it, you make the `struct` instance `const`, not the member.

Comment: I'm using Arduino so it keeps confusing me because it can use either C or C++. So frankly, I'm not too sure

Comment: The code you posted is very likely c++, there is no **new** operator in c and in my opinion that operator is just crazy ---. But it must be used in c++, it exists because when you allocate a c++ class dynamically you don't need to call the constructor explicitly, instead you just use the **new** operator, and freeing **new**ed memory requires the **delete** operator.

Comment: There are other fields inside the struct that change. I mean truthfully I am never going to access those variables inside my struct aside from initialization. So I would be OK just setting it as a regular variable, but for completeness sake I was hoping to make it constant.

Comment: Then don't, `const` does not guarantee that you wont, so just don't, and if you want to be very very sure, then don't use the struct directly but through accessor functions, that way you keep it safe.

Comment: Ahh okay. It's been a while since I used `C`, but I would like to keep my code in as much `C` as possible, so for initialization it would be `Sensor *left = (Sensor *)malloc(sizeOf Sensor *);`

Comment: Yes but without the cast, it's not good style to cast the return value of functions return `void *` because `void *` is guaranteed to be converted to any pointer type without a cast by the c standard.

Comment: Awesome. Got it. Thanks for the help. Just trying to over complicate things here

Answer (score 4):

Unless there's something weird going on, you don't need dynamic allocation here. If the type is an aggregate, then you can simply initialise it in the declaration:

```
Sensor left = {1 /*, other variables */};
```

If it's not an aggregate, then the `const` member will have to be initialised in a constructor:

```
struct Sensor {
    const unsigned char pin;
    //otherVariables

    Sensor(unsigned char pin) : pin(pin)
        //, other variables
    {}
};
```

(I took the liberty of removing the weird C-style `typedef`. In C++, that's just pointless noise.)